# By using Neyman-Pearson, how do I know if the most powerful test is also UMP?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

I understand that the Neyman Pearson Lemma gives us the most powerful test for a certain alternative simple hypothesis. I also understand by definition, a most powerful test is also UMP if it gives us the largest power for any composite alternative hypothesis.

So once I have the most powerful test for a certain simple alternative hypothesis, how do I know if that's also UMP? Do I have to calculate the power of the test for every possible value in the composite hypothesis? Or is there a much simple way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the Karlin-Rubin theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem